# spread operator giving issue with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, immutable.js, reactjs.net

I am trying to implement a redux store for my react-typescript app. I am having a problem in my reducer. In native react-apps I did the following

```
  reminders = [...state, reminder(action)];
  return reminders;
```

the spread operator works perfectly. and the new object is added to array immutably.

with typescript this is not happening.(get an empty object instead of an array) I tried object.assign

```
  return (<any>Object).assign({}, state, reminder(action));
```

This replaces the current object rather then adding it to the array and I dont think its doing it in an immutable way.

I tried uisng immutable.js and the reducer was not being called at all.

```
 return map([state,reminder(action)])
```

no idea what is wrong. also after using objext.assign the nextprops and currents props always come same. even if it is changed in the shouldContainerUpdate() method

Comment: `with typescript this is not happening` can you describe what is happening? what is the value of `reminders`? is it missing `reminder(action)`?

Comment: im getting an empty object instead of an array

Comment: what are the contents of `state`?

Comment: state is empty initially

Comment: `reminders = [ ...state, reminder(action)]` is working in my case, not sure what's your issue

Comment: i get state.concat is not a function after webpack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the spread operator works perfectly. and the new object is added to array immutably.

Use the exact same in TypeScript and it will work perfectly:

```
reminders = [...state, reminder(action)];
return reminders;
```

## Why

Because TypeScript follows the same semantics as JavaScript for JavaScript syntax

Comment: its not working. I always get an empty object instead on an array.