# `Trace: TypeError: React.__spread is not a function`

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, babeljs

I was seeing a warning about this when I was using **React 15** and I can't remember what exactly the warning was. But I am using **React 16** now and my app is breaking with this error saying:

`Trace: TypeError: React.__spread is not a function`

I am using spread operator `{...props}`. Is this making this issue?

**Edit:**
Babel not transforming spread operator and need to use `babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread` to use spread operator and I tried the same.
But it is also not working. Further investigation turns out that we may need some other plugins like `'transform-es2015-spread', 'transform-es2015-parameters', 'transform-es2015-destructuring'` like so to work(?) .

I kind of tried every combination of plugins/presets which still fails to compile spread operator in Babel.

Below giving babel package.json:

```
"babel-core": "^6.25.0",
"babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
"babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring": "^6.23.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-es2015-spread": "^6.22.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-es2015-parameters": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-es2015-tree-shaking": "^1.0.1",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
```

and react dependencies:

```
"react": "^16.0.0",
"react-dom": "^16.0.0",
"react-redux": "^5.0.6",
"react-router-dom": "^4.1.2",
```

This is more of a babel issue. And the babel configuration I am using is:

```
const BABEL_PRESET = {
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  options: {
    presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
    plugins: ['transform-es2015-spread', 'transform-es2015-parameters', 'transform-es2015-destructuring']
  }
};
```

**Note:** This is the configuration I last tried. I have tried another couple of configurations too.

Comment: are you sure you are using the latest version of react and typescript?

Comment: No typescript, React version is 16

Comment: coz I had asked a similar question before. and the answer they gave turned out to be right https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47298885/spread-operator-giving-issue-with-typescript

Comment: no typescript then the problem is somewhere else, as native react supports spread

Comment: I have found, in most cases such errors are a symptom of some other error and not the cause of the error itself, like you forgot to add a reference or some value was undefined etc

Comment: https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/react-internal-nav/issues/1

Comment: Its likely that one of the libraries that you use hasn't fixed it or you need to upgrade it

Comment: `React.__spread` has been removed in React16. The reason you are getting the error could be that you are using `JSXTransformer` which compiles the spread attribute to `React.__spread`. If that's the case then rather use `Babel` also because `JSXTransformer` has not been maintained for about two years now

Comment: I am using babel and I have given the details of the configuration in the question

Comment: Okay, great. Have you tried using the `transform-object-rest-spread` plugin or `stage-2` preset

Comment: `transform-es2015-destructuring` involves `a(...a)`, `[...d]` over lists/arrays. It is different for objects

Comment: `transform-object-rest-spread` was the first plugin I used, Then came to these three. Now I tried the `react-app` preset from `create-react-app` still not working. I am thinking I am foolishly missing something else. I checked things and all looks fine. Will try again and if got any solution will update here.

Comment: Since this is a `stage-2` feature, have you tried that?

Comment: No. not yet. I will try that. But I am not sure about using `stage-2` because it may not goto actual release? And can you tell me how to use it?

Comment: Oh well, yeah, you are right, it's not a very safe solution. Anyway, according to the babel documentation, the order of plugins matters. Haha :D, so, also try `['transform-es2015-destructuring', 'transform-object-rest-spread', 'transform-es2015-parameters']`

Answer (score 0):

You can add this dependency : `"babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread"`

Then add it in .babelrc :

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["react"], ["env"]
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```